# SQL login works from management studio and windows terminal but failes from external application with adodb - object

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have the following problem:
OS Win 10 Prof x64,
SQL 2017 Standard instance,
SQL User with Password are configured.

Login to the database with the user via Management Studio works.
Login to the database with the user via the terminal works.
System - DSN ODBC connections with the user and password work.
When connecting to the database from external application with the OLEDB object, I get an entry in the SQL message log:  Login failed for user 'xy'. Reason: Password did not matched for the login provided.
Error: 18456, severity 14, state 8

connection String is constructed as follows:

```
PointSet P & "MES.LOOPS.SQL", 0         
Set SQLCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set SQLrst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

SQLCon.ConnectionTimeOut = anyValue
SQLCon.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
SQLCon.Properties("Data Source").Value = PointGet(P & "$PROJECT.COMPUTER") & "\" & "cimplicity"
SQLCon.Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = "DB_NAME"
SQLCon.Properties("User ID").Value = "anyUser"
SQLCon.Properties("Password").Value = "password of user"
```

have any of you ever had the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: Is `xy` the same `anyUser`? If yes, then it is possible that password contains typos or apostrophs or UTF-8 characters or something similar. Copy password value to userid one and look at SQL log :)

Comment: hey jarlh, thank you for your reply. 'xy' and 'anyUser' are just example stings for this post. it is of course one user with one password. I cannot follow your suggestoin. can you explain it little more detailed?

Comment: If you have a special char on password try to replace it with simple char and retry maybe is only a problem of escaping.

Comment: already tried. password contains simple letter like 'sqlbackdoor'. I also tried to create an new user but it did not helped either.
I think it is related to windows security, but I did not find remedy yet. So Please if some one has a hint feel free to comment.

Comment: Could it be a letter case issue? SQL Login passwords are case-sensitive, so `sqlbackdoor` is not the same as `SqlBackdoor`.

Comment: It is not the reason, it is all low case.

Answer (score 0):

To all who are facing the same issue:

You have to provide security information to your connection string. In my case I had to remove the Parameter “User ID” and “Password” and add parameter “Integrated Security=SSPI” instead and it worked. By the way, it is recommended to use windows authentication method

```
SQLCon.ConnectionTimeOut = anyValue
SQLCon.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
SQLCon.Properties("Data Source").Value = PointGet(P & "$PROJECT.COMPUTER") & "\" & "cimplicity"
SQLCon.Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = "DB_NAME"
'SQLCon.Properties("User ID").Value = "anyUser"'
'SQLCon.Properties("Password").Value = "password of user"'
SQLCon.Properties("Integrated Security").Value = "SSIP"
```

Detailed information about SQL login is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax

@Microsoft anoter entry in SQL logging but "wrong password" would be more helpful...

Comment: That seems incorrect.  "Integrated Security" is windows auth, and that does NOT require a password to be supplied in the connection string.  Seems like one place you use SQL auth, and another place windows auth.

Comment: Password property is commented in the code. I left it there to track what I changed

Comment: But it's wasn't commented out above (you have now fixed). Source Control is for tracking code changes. You are using Source Code Control, right?